# Aggregation two table

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have two tables

`nameTB` contains:

```
id  |  name  |  gender  | nationalityid
```

`nationalityTB` contains:

nationalityid  |  nationalityname

I want create sql query to return the result:

```
nationalityname            female              male        total
UK                         10                  5           15
USA                        11                  7           18
```

Comment: What db platform are you using?  MySql, MS Sql, ...?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to easily get the result by joining the tables and using an aggregate function with conditional logic (like a CASE expression):

```
select nt.nationalityname,
    sum(case when nm.gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) Female,
    sum(case when nm.gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) Male,
    count(*) Total
from nationalityTB nt
left join nameTB nm
    on nt.nationalityid = nm.nationalityid
group by nt.nationalityname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/223e8/1)